# How to build applications for windows pre-installation environment (Windows PE)?

Tags: c++, c, windows

I am new to c++, and I understand that the windows pe is very limited on library support, therefore everything must be written natively. This is what I have so far

```
// test.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//


#include "stdafx.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <wimgapi.h>

DWORD
WINAPI
SampleCaptureCallback(
    IN      DWORD msgId,    //message ID
    IN      WPARAM param1,   //usually file name
    INOUT   LPARAM param2,   //usually error code
    IN      void  *unused
    )
{
    //First parameter: full file path for if WIM_MSG_PROCESS, message string for others
    TCHAR *message  = (TCHAR *) param1;
    TCHAR *filePath = (TCHAR *) param1;
    DWORD percent   = (DWORD)   param1;

    //Second parameter: message back to caller if WIM_MSG_PROCESS, error code for others
    DWORD errorCode = param2;
    DWORD *msg_back = (DWORD *) param2;
    DWORD seconds = (DWORD) param2;


    switch ( msgId )
    {
        case WIM_MSG_PROGRESS:

            // Prints out the current progress percentage.
            //
            system("cls");

            wprintf(L"__________________\n\n| Capture process|\t\t\n__________________\n\n%d %% captured. About %i seconds(s) remaining - %i minute(s)", (DWORD)param1, ((INT)seconds / 1000), ((INT)seconds / 60000));

            break;
        case WIM_MSG_PROCESS:

            //This message is sent for each file, capturing to see if callee intends to
            //capture the file or not.
            //
            //If you do not intend to capture this file, then assign FALSE in msg_back
            //and still return WIM_MSG_SUCCESS.
            //Default is TRUE.
            //

            //In this example, print out the file name being applied
            //
            //_tprintf(TEXT("FilePath: %s\n"), filePath);

            break;

        case WIM_MSG_ERROR:

            //This message is sent upon failure error case
            //
            printf("ERROR: %s [err = %d]\n", message, errorCode);
            break;

        case WIM_MSG_RETRY:

            //This message is sent when the file is being reapplied because of
            //network timeout. Retry is done up to five times.
            //
            printf("RETRY: %s [err = %d]\n", message, errorCode);
            break;

        case WIM_MSG_INFO:

            //This message is sent when informational message is available
            //
            printf("INFO: %s [err = %d]\n", message, errorCode);
            break;

        case WIM_MSG_WARNING:

            //This message is sent when warning message is available
            //
            printf("WARNING: %s [err = %d]\n", message, errorCode);
            break;
    }

    return WIM_MSG_SUCCESS;
}

void
SampleCaptureCleanup ( HANDLE hWim, HANDLE hImg, FARPROC callback )
{
    if (hImg) {
        WIMCloseHandle (hImg);
    }

    if (hWim) {
        WIMCloseHandle (hWim);
    }

    if (callback) {
        WIMUnregisterMessageCallback( NULL, callback );
    }
}



int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HANDLE hWim = NULL;
    HANDLE hImg = NULL;
    DWORD  created = 0;
    DWORD  oFlag = 0, oAccess = 0;
    FARPROC callback = (FARPROC) SampleCaptureCallback;

    TCHAR *wimFile    = TEXT("C:\\work\\work.wim");  //destination .wim file
    TCHAR *tmpDir     = TEXT("C:\\work");               //temporary directory: OPTIONAL
    TCHAR *captureDir = TEXT("C:\\work");               //capture directory or drive

    SetConsoleTitle(L"Recovery");

    //generic capture/append call sequence
    //
    //w = WIMCreateFile()
    //WIMSetTemporaryPath() - optional
    //i = WIMCaptureImage()
    //WIMCloseHandle(i)
    //WIMCloseHandle(w)
    //

    //Set up access mode and open flag
    //
    if (argc < 1 || argc > 2) {
        SetLastError(ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER);
        return 1;
    }

    if (argc == 1) {                        //capture
        oFlag   = WIM_CREATE_ALWAYS;
        oAccess = WIM_GENERIC_WRITE;
    }
    else if (*argv[1] != TEXT('a')) {       //append
        printf("need 'a' to append\n");
        SetLastError(ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER);
        return 2;
    }
    else {
        oFlag   = WIM_OPEN_EXISTING;
        oAccess = WIM_GENERIC_WRITE | WIM_GENERIC_READ;
    }

    //Register callback
    //
    if (WIMRegisterMessageCallback( NULL,
                                    callback,
                                    NULL ) == INVALID_CALLBACK_VALUE) {
        printf ("Cannot set callback\n");
        return 3;
    }

    //Call SampleCleanup() upon exit from here
    //
    hWim = WIMCreateFile ( wimFile,             //existing .wim file to append to
                           oAccess,             //access mode
                           oFlag,               //open flag
                           0, // WIM_FLAG_VERIFY,     //recommended flag for file corruption check
                           WIM_COMPRESS_LZX, //or WIM_COMPRESS_LZX or WIM_COMPRESS_NONE
                           &created );

    if ( !hWim ) {
        printf ("Cannot open WIM file\n");

        SampleCaptureCleanup(hWim, hImg, callback);
        return 4;
    }

    //set temporary directory to work in
    //OPTIONAL, but recommended for large WIM file
    //
    //WIMSetTemporaryPath (hWim, tmpDir);         //OK to fail.

    //Now capture or append image
    //
    hImg = WIMCaptureImage ( hWim,
                             captureDir,  //capture directory or drive
                             0);          //WIM_FLAG_VERIFY

    if ( !hImg )
    {
        printf ("Cannot capture/append image\n");
        SampleCaptureCleanup (hWim, hImg, callback);
        return 5;
    }

    //Now we are done
    //
    SampleCaptureCleanup (hWim, hImg, callback);

    system("cls");
    wprintf(L"_____________\n\n| COMPLETED |\n_____________\n\nPress any key to exit...");

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

It runs fine in windows, but when I run it in windows pe it says that the application has has crashed and the error code is 0xc000007b. My question is how to do I make it compile be a native application? I think that using wprintf isn't native? Am I wrong? Thanks for helping!

Comment: Were you switching from 64 bit to 32 bit, etc.?

Comment: i think it's set at 32 - bit compiled, does it matter? I'm pretty sure that the windows PE image is 64 .. should I try compiling it in 64 bit?

Comment: how do i change it to x64? I am using the wimgapi.h and wimgapi.lib. But when I try to compile it won't let me compile. It says that the wimgapi.lib file can not be found

Comment: Yep, I don't think PE includes WOW64, so you need to compile  for the correct architecture.

Comment: I actually just made a brand new x86 winpe iso booted it and tried to run it and now it's complaining that the WIMGAPI.DLL isn't designed for windows. I know that there are applications that use this dll in windows pe. OEM's develop applications that use it as well.

Answer (score 0):

2 tips when C/C++ coding for PE environments
1) PE does not include WOW then you aways have to use a 64 bit version of your code on a 64 bit PE environment.
2) Make the C/C++ Run Time Library statically linked.